# Why do I have a message about "mxpnl.net" always in my Google Chrome console?

Tags: javascript

> VM2335:34152 POST https://cr-input.mxpnl.net/data?_channel_id=&_partner_id=39571&_sub_id=0000&_app_version=1.0.23&_app=cs-dca net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

Comment: Well...is the internet disconnected?

Comment: I seem to recall Mxpnl is an analytics service, though of course this might not be their domain.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can find, it appears to be a behaviour and analytic tracking script most likely related to [mixpanel.com](https://mixpanel.com/). I've recently run into the same thing, and followed it back to the content.js file inside the [Tampermonkey chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo). I'm sure there are other chrome extensions that do the same thing, but uninstalling this chrome extension made the https://cr-input.mxpnl.net request stop.

I've also heard others have solved this problem by uninstalling Hide my adBlocker, but I can't confirm this myself.

Answer (score 0):

This *could* mean you have a malicious Chrome extension installed. I googled "cr-input mxpnl" and came across [this Google Forums post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/UbToGGmN-MM;context-place=topicsearchin/chrome/authorid$3AAPn2wQd85HISDrXjjhFjDqD7F9dwljp38-HYuzfvv1-oM2BMAGyMmTr89TVpc6DFOk0UK_nWQnDE%7Csort:date%7Cspell:false). If your internet is disconnected, the extension is probably failing to connect to the website where it wants to send your data.

To be clear, this is a guess. It may be a totally legit extension. However it would definitely be worth checking what extensions are installed, removing any that you don't recognise and doing a virus scan.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using some Adblocker extension that's the reason for getting 
`ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED` from the console. In the preferences of your Adblocker, you have blocked the access to Site Analytics Tracker

Turning off or Disabling the **`Web Statistic Tracker`** options from the preferences of the installed extension came from the [Tampermonkey chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo). That alone stops accessing ***analytic tracking script*** most likely related to [mixpanel.com](https://mixpanel.com/).

There are other options from the preferences from the extension that might not be needed

- **Cheap Flights Advisor**
- **PromoBar**
- **Aliradar**

So try to disable these options and always try to block all unencrypted requests by using [**HTTPS Everywhere**](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) extensions so that your information might not be stolen to any third party agents.